# Executing different kernels on different GPUs simultaneously

Tags: opencl

Basically I have two GPUs and I want to execute some kernels on each of them. I don't want the GPUs to be working on the same kernel with each doing some part of it(I don know if this is possible), just in case I don even want to see that behavior.

I just want to make sure that both the devices are being exercised. I have created context and the command queues for both of them. But I see only one kernel gets executed which means only one device is being used. This is how I have done it. . .

```
cl_device_id *device;
cl_kernel *kernels;
...
// creating context.  
context = clCreateContext(0, num_devices, device, NULL, NULL, &error);
...
// creating command queues for all kernels
for(int i = 0; i<num_kenrels; i++)
    cmdQ[i] = clCreateCommandQueue(context, *device, 0, &error);
...
// enqueue kernels 
error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(*cmdQ, *kernels, 2, 0, glbsize, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Am I going the correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how you actually filled your `device` array. In case you initialized it correctly, creating the `context` spanning the devices is correct.

Unfortunately, you have a wrong idea about kernels and command queues. A *kernel* is created from a program for a particular context. A *queue* on the other hand is used to communicate with a certain device. What you want to do is create one queue per device *not* kernel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_devices; i++)
    cmdQ[i] = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device[i], 0, &error);
```

Now you can enqueue the different (or same) kernels on different devices via the corresponding command queues:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQ[0], kernels[0], /* ... */);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQ[1], kernels[1], /* ... */);
```

To sum up the terms:

- A `cl_context` is created for a particular `cl_platform_id` and is like a container for a subset of devices,
- a `cl_program` is created and built for a `cl_context` and its associated devices
- a `cl_kernel` is extracted from a `cl_program` but can only be used on devices associated with the program's context,
- a `cl_command_queue` is created for a specific device belonging to a certain context,
- memory operations and kernel calls are enqueued in a command queue and executed on the corresponding device.

Comment: Agreed. Also note that different implementations handle distributing workloads across multiple device differently (and sometimes even block clEnqueueNDRangeKernel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562543/clenqueuendrange-blocking-on-nvidia-hardware-also-multi-gpu/11562814#comment15294577_11562814) - and in some cases might be less performant. To truly separate processing across two devices and control it all yourself, you can use two contexts, each created with one device.

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick question, can I not use a single clEnqueueNDRangeKernel statement to start both the kernels?

Comment: No, not really. But inside an OpenCL program you can call other functions defined in the same program, if you really just want to split up the logic.

Comment: @matthias :I tried running the kernels on different devices exactly the same way as you suggested. I have even maintained different context for each device. The first kernel executes correctly but I get an "Access violation reading location" eror when the second NDRangeKernel is encountered. I see that memory is allocated correctly and no NULL pointers as such.. Why is this error occurring ?